# Programatically Loading an Excel Automation Server in C#

Tags: excel, c#-4.0, office-interop, com-interop

I would like to add a User Defined Function to Excel at run-time in C# using something like the following from my add-in:

```
this.Application.RegisterXLL(@"C:\addins\UDF.dll"); // OK
this.Application.AddIns.Add("MyAddin.Functions"); // Error
this.Application.AddIns["MyAddin.Functions"].Installed = true;
```

Instead of doing something manual like [this](https://www.quantnet.com/threads/how-to-create-udf-in-excel-using-c-and-visual-studio-2008.1260/). However, I don't understand how I:

1. Load the actual dll (my add-in installer will register this for COM interop)
2. Add the actual functions

Any ideas?

Comment: Would this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/606446/UsingplusC-plus-NETplusUserplusDefinedplusFuncti) be of use to the above problem?

Comment: I saw this but it also uses the manual method.